# How to handle C exceptions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a bunch of C functions in my Objective-C project iOS app, that can potentially crash. I want to be able to handle those crashed. At first, I thought to use @try-catch mechanism, but as far as I understand, all exceptions inside this block must be thrown to be handled. Is it true? How can I solve my problem?

For example, this is a call of a C function in Objective-C code. Potentially this function can crush.

```
err = mailimap_list(session, "", "*", &allList);
```

Comment: "How can I solve my problem?" Make sure your C code does not crash.

Comment: [The documentation](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=fc2c80ae0712120029m1bb8508eibdadb474ffa9e598%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=libetpan-devel) suggests that you need to check the returned error code--in your code, `err`--namely, check that it is not `MAILIMAP_NO_ERROR`.  Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: No, this function sometimes doesn't even return err. It just crashes inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: you can't.

Long explanation: C doesn't have "exceptions". If C code crashes, that's something fatal concerning the life of the process. For example, a detected segmentation fault will make the OS terminate your process. These are not nice Obejctive-C-style exceptions which can be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Is there such thing as 'C exceptions' ?
If they don't exist, you don't have to handle them : problem solved !